# In Spark RDD Println Error, How can I present the Data such as [Ljava.lang.String;@8e6606

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, rdd

I have one problem with Apache Spark, using Scala. I'm trying to create a Spark application that prints an RDD from user input. Input data is like this:

```
List("aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa","aaaa","dfddf")
```

Code is like this:

```
    val wSchemaString = "col1 col2 col3 col4";
    val wSchema = StructType(wSchemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)));
    val wRow = sc.parallelize(wInput.map(_.split(",")));
    val wRowRDD = wRow.map(x=>{
        val wNum = wSchemaString.split(" ").size;
        var out = new Array[String](wNum+1);
        for(i <- 0 to wNum)
        {
            out(i) = x(i);
        }
        Row(out);
    });

wRowRDD.collect.foreach(println);
...
```

Result is like this:

```
27 [[Ljava.lang.String;@5f1ec010]
28 [[Ljava.lang.String;@5bd38b39]
29 [[Ljava.lang.String;@5d6b1c05]
30 [[Ljava.lang.String;@7ea6404c]
31 [[Ljava.lang.String;@75447fda]
32 [[Ljava.lang.String;@6425fd5b]
33 [[Ljava.lang.String;@7a1c94ba]
34 [[Ljava.lang.String;@6a687df7]
35 [[Ljava.lang.String;@722619b4]
36 [[Ljava.lang.String;@117d1979]
37 [[Ljava.lang.String;@304a45f4]
38 [[Ljava.lang.String;@5c36aef0]
39 [[Ljava.lang.String;@a173ddc]
40 [[Ljava.lang.String;@7bde3bb0]
41 [[Ljava.lang.String;@3b20df58]
42 [[Ljava.lang.String;@981f1f2
```

**But, what I want is this:**

```
"aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa"
"aaaa","dfddf","aaaa","aaaa"
"dfddf","aaaa","aaaa","dfddf"    
"aaaa","aaaa","dfddf","aaaa"
```

Answer (score 3):

Row is an Array[Any] so the String that is generated in the prinln function is the one generated by the Array's toString method.

To get the output these output you have to do something like:

```
val wSchemaString = "col1 col2 col3 col4";
val wSchema = StructType(wSchemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)));
val wRow = sc.parallelize(wInput.map(_.split(",")));
val wRowRDD = wRow.map(x=>{
    val wNum = wSchemaString.split(" ").size;
    var out = new Array[String](wNum+1);
    for(i <- 0 to wNum)
    {
        out(i) = x(i);
    }
    Row(out);
});

wRowRDD.collect.foreach(row => println(row.mkString(",")));
```

I hope these will be useful

Comment: It is thanks to your help.^o^ but problem is still same. And I have one question. last code(println(row, .mkString(",")) is available? I reach error message - illlegal start of simple expression. In case, your code is row.mkString(",")? Then. I fix your code. but problem is stll. Have you any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure what any of this code is, but yes, the `,` was definitely a typo in @jlopezmat's answer. I think you also need to replace `Row(out)` with `out`.

Comment: Thank you @DanielDarabos and sorry. my code is just a piece and sample, I want to make schemaRDD and register table. And use spark-sql(ex:select * from tablename).  And send the result data to unix domain socket. But, I  received uncorrect data such as [[Ljava.lang.String;@5f1ec010. Becauseof using Spark-Sql, I should make a RowRDD.